# How to send Query Parameters in Android HttpPost

Tags: android, http-post, query-string

I am developing an Android app, in which I need to consume a web service. I am getting the 200 response when I check in SoapUI ( I am not able to attach my SoapUI screen shot). Basically I need to send the query parameters to a login web service which is a POST request.

I am trying the below code snippet in my Android file, but it is not working. Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
String loginUrl = "http://my-login-portal.in/LogonServlet";

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);

nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", "/OrderHandlingServlet?api=login"));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtDomain", "MyDomain"));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtUid", "user1"));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtPwd", "pwd1"));


httppost = new HttpPost(loginUrl);
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));                
httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code :

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);

nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", "/OrderHandlingServlet?api=login"));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtDomain", "MyDomain"));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtUid", "user1"));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtPwd", "pwd1"));

HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, INSERTCONNECTIONTIMEOUT);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);//put url here
request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) client.execute(request);
String data = StreamToString(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent());
```

Comment: Hi Saman, tried the above - but no luck. What value should I give to INSERTCONNECTIONTIMEOUT? Not sure of what I am missing here

Comment: INSERTCONNECTIONTIMEOUT must be set with int number that means maximum time for connecting wait.also make sure have internet permission